# Why is the circle getting cut off?

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

Steps:

1. Make a brand new "Blank App (Universal Windows)"
2. Set Target and Minimum Version: "Windows 10 Creators Update (10.0; Build 15063)"
3. Add the code below to MainPage.xaml and run the app.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid Width="128" Height="120">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="120" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1" x:Name="ChangeHeightRow" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Background="Red">
            <Ellipse Width="140" Height="140" Fill="Green" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Should see this:

[image: Unexpected result]

Why is the green circle getting cut off? Further to that, if you set `ChangeHeightRow.Height` to `0`, it looks like this:

[image: Expected result]

What is going on? I would expect the circle to *never* be cut off...maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Because your Grid Width is 128 and Height is 120 but your Ellipse Width is 140 and Height is 140

Comment: @AVKNaidu, then why does it stop getting cut off in the second case?

Comment: Still the same. Your circle is larger than the grid. and You are basically stacking the circle on grid when there is no second row. Thats why.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: You are clipping of the `Ellipse` by having an empty row of 1 pixel in your `Grid`.

The problem is on multiple levels. Your outer `Grid` has a `Width` and `Height` set. Next your `RowDefinition` has a `Height` set and your `Ellipse` is of a bigger size than both heights.

```
<Grid Width="128" Height="120">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="120" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1" x:Name="ChangeHeightRow" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Background="Red">
            <Ellipse Width="140" Height="140" Fill="Green" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

By setting these sizes, you are allowing other controls to come closer to the inner controls than they would if you would use `Auto` as sizing for the rows and nothing (=auto) as `Grid` size.

In your initial code, you have a `Grid` row with the `Ellipse` and an empty row of 1 pixel high. By default XAML controls have a Z-axis with items declared at the bottom of your XAML file being the topmost control in the visual layers. So for your Grid, your second row is on top of your first row in case of overlap. Since the `Ellipse` leaks outside of the row, the second row is drawn over it and clips your `Ellipse`.

By setting the height to 0, the second row is no longer drawn and can't clip your control.

---

To make this more clear, I have tweaked your XAML a bit, adding another `StackPanel` outside your grid and adding a `Button`. As you can see, the Button is drawn on top of the `Ellipse`, as it's defined below in XAML and thus getting a higher visual layer on the Z-axis.

```
<StackPanel Width="130">
    <Grid Width="128" Height="120">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="120" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0" x:Name="ChangeHeightRow" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Canvas Background="Red">
                <Ellipse Width="140" Height="140" Fill="Green" />
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Button Background="Black" Foreground="White">Test</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

[image: Button below]

If we change the StackPanel to a Grid, we have the same behavior. However moving the Button to the top in the XAML declaration (and keeping Grid.Row on 1 so it's below the Ellipse), you'll notice that it's now behind the Ellipse because of the Z-layers ordered differently.

```
<Grid Width="130">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Background="Black" Foreground="White" Grid.Row="1">Test</Button>
    <Grid Width="128" Height="120" Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="120" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0" x:Name="ChangeHeightRow" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Canvas Background="Red">
                <Ellipse Width="140" Height="140" Fill="Green" />
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: "the second row is drawn over it and clips your Ellipse." Why does the second row drawing over it result in clipping though? This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: "That's how XAML works".
You're already cheating the sizing by combining Grid-Canvas-Ellipse. Take out the Canvas and it will be always clipped. First row has Z-index of e.g. 0, second row z-index of 1 (spanning the whole width) and basicly saying "layer 0, you're done, it's my turn".

Comment: Here's a more complex version of my problem which demonstrates that the second row is always drawn and seems to debunk the theory that it's a z-index issue. https://gist.github.com/trevordunn/b415d420e7378858c0329d62476ef8af

Seems more so related to the heights (which still doesn't make sense to me) and not their order or whether or not they're being rendered.